# Azure DevOps Pipeline Task error - can not find a part of the path while using Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand

Tags: azure-devops

Im trying to run the Powershell Script on Azure Windows VM using Azure DevOps release pipeline with Azure PowerShell task and Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand in powershell.
Im using this example

```
Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' -Name 'vmname' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'scriptpath' -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}
```

and running this command in Azure devOps Release pipeline using Azure PowerShell Task.

Im getting the error that the path of the ScriptPath is not found.
What path should we provide here.

Answer (score 1):

In the script that you gave, the value of `CommandId` is `RunPowerShellScript`, which means to run a custom PowerShell script.

The value of `ScriptPath` represents the path to your custom PowerShell script file that needs to be executed. Its default value is `none`.

For more information about the `Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand`, please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/invoke-azurermvmruncommand?view=azurermps-6.13.0#examples). Here is the document's interpretation of the `ScriptPath` parameter:

> Path of the script to be executed. When this value is given, the given script will override the default script of the command.

Comment: Thanks Jane. But which script path to be given here? I want to run a script in Azure VM from Azure devOps Pipeline. When I provide the path of the script stored in Azure VM ('C\users\Documents\Testconnection.ps1), its gives error "can not find a part of the path". When I keep the file in azure Git repo and provide that path, still it gives the same error.

Comment: @Yogesh Kulkarni Maybe you could try the `Get-Location` command to get the current path?